# Set limit on maximum size of bucket in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry, google-cloud-storage

I am using Google Cloud Storage(GCS) to store some images, and want to set a limit on the maximum size the bucket can reach.

The actual use case is, I will be using Google Container Registry(GCR), which in turn uses GCS to store the images.
I don't want the bucket size or the total repository to cross 100Gb(or X Gb).
I have been looking for a way to set this limit using some GCP configuration but to no avail.

I know I can keep checking the bucket size at regular intervals to keep it in check. But is there a way where I can set the hard-limit on the max size of a GCS bucket?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set a limit on the size of a Cloud Storage bucket using Google Cloud management controls or constraints.

Additionally, buckets used by Container Registry and Artifact Registry are best left alone. If you want to control the size, delete images that you are no longer using manually. Do not delete objects as images consist of multiple objects (image layers). A container image is usually not a single file (object). Poor management will result in orphan objects and broken services that use those images.

Technically, you can write your own function to monitor those buckets. Please reread the previous paragraph to understand the challenges in managing the total used space.